# MongoDB as a queue, capped collection + tailable cursor

Tags: c#, mongodb, message-queue

(asked on mongo-user discussion group https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongodb-user/i1ge4bNiMgM/discussion)

Hi, i'd like to use MongoDB as a message queue and thought about using a capped collection + tailable cursor for that purpose.
I know that the tailable cursor can be used for accessing documents in the insertion order but

1. can I use any sort order for the cursor?
2. does a tailing cursor work with a filter query (to skip some documents I don't want to process)? If so, how does it handle insertion of new documents - will I be notified only if the new document matches the query criteria?
3. Are tailing cursors fully supported by C# driver?
4. I'd like my queue to guarantee single delivery - I mean if two clients try to read messages from the same collection they shouldn't be able to 'consume' the same message. I think this could be achieved with findAndModify, but how to do that with tailing cursor?

Thanks 
RG

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was a presentation from AOL/About.me on "[MongoDB as message queue](http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/mongodb-as-message-queue)" at the Silicon Valley MUG in April, 2012 that you may find helpful in planning your approach.

> 1. can I use any sort order for the cursor?
> 2. does a tailing cursor work with a filter query (to skip some documents I don't want to process)? If so, how does it handle insertion of new documents - will I be notified only if the new document matches the query criteria?

A tailable cursor tails the *end* of a capped collection and only in natural order.  If you want a sort order you need to use an indexed query instead.

Please have a read of the [Create Tailable Cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) documentation page for more information.

> Are tailing cursors fully supported by C# driver?

Yes, tailable cursor support was implemented in the 1.1 C# driver (see: [code example](http://www.pastie.org/1977343)).

> I'd like my queue to guarantee single delivery - I mean if two clients try to read messages from the same collection they shouldn't be able to 'consume' the same message. I think this could be achieved with findAndModify, but how to do that with tailing cursor?

There are a few approaches:

- Have a single reader with the tailable cursor distribute tasks to worker threads (i.e. based on worker queue depth or round-robin). This will be more efficient than having multiple readers, but is potentially a single point of failure.
- (suggested by @Contango in comment below) Have multiple readers, but use optimistic concurrency to ensure that only one worker "owns" each task. This will result in more I/O, but may simplify your design if the workers are also tailing directly.

For more information on atomic operations, see [Isolate Sequence of Operations](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/isolate-sequence-of-operations/) in the MongoDB manual.

Comment: Thanks, I think this explains why there are so few examples of using tailable cursor

Comment: The code sample appears to be down.  I mirrored it here: https://gist.github.com/tekmaven/5842521

Comment: I disagree with the statement "Based on your use case, I dont think tailable cursors would be a helpful approach.". It could be done with the same principle as optimistic concurrency uses. Each consumer increments a sequence number on the item it has just read, and writes just the sequence number back. If the sequence number comes back as one, then the consumer owns it. If it comes back as two or more,  then the consumer discards it. This works as each individual record is locked by default in Mongo.  I might have to write some code to demo this.

Comment: @Contango: You can certainly use some sort of optimistic concurrency for multiple readers (as you suggest) but this doesn't seem overly efficient. The statement there was definitely too broad, though. I think it would be better to have one reader tailing and handing out tasks to multiple workers. I think my comment on tailable cursor was more in relation to wanting to tail by sort order but that was a few years ago :).

Comment: Each tailing reader is essentially polling though, correct?  If that is the case (as it seems to be from what I've read and observed), then multiple tailing readers would just bog the system down too much I would think.  Am I right on that?